# Overload pyqtProperty

Tags: properties, pyqt, overloading

I have a custom widget which I'm using in a QWizard. It has a property called path, which can be a Path object (from pathlib), or None. I implemented this as a plain python property, but I need to change it to a pyqtProperty so I can use it as a field in the wizard.

Is it possible to overload the property so that it can work with None as well as Path?

Comment: I'm bound to ask: why don't you just try it, and see what happens? Also: have you read the [pyqt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html#defining-new-qt-properties) on this topic?

Comment: I did, it didn't work! Not that there was a documented method on how to do it! Eventually I found I could use pyqtProperty('QVariant') I'll write an answer up when I get a moment for anybody else who might be stuck on something like this.